# Find anagrams in a file

Tags: python, anagram

I want a program to find anagrams in a file. For example:

```
>>>anagram('words.txt', 'top')
top
pot
```

The file will contain a long list of words with no spaces.

```
tapmatlamebrainfamelookcookkoolkoocnamemane
```

This is my current code:

```
def anagrams(filename, word):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    if not word:
        return ['']
    ret = []
    for i, d in enumerate(word):
        perms = anagrams(word[:i] + word[i+1:])
        for perm in perms:
            ret.append(d + perm)
    for i in ret:
        if i in infile:
            print (i)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: how do you expect to seperate the words in the textfile to not match something like gl*otp*aul

Comment: right now i run a permutation function, then find if any of those are in the file. But that seems to not work, cause It returns nothing

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. Could you please provide a sample input and output?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Its at the top read it again

Comment: @JasonSchayer: Your question is still ambiguous. What was the purpose of using `itertools.permutations` the way you did? Would you accept non-English words returned by the anagram finder function?

Comment: i don't know how you can ever hope to make this work without some word boundaries on the input

Comment: i didnt add the intertools, that was someone else. I will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what I think you want it to do

```
def anagram(filepath, word):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        text = ''.join(line.strip() for line in file)
    for i in xrange(len(text)-len(word):
        prop = text[i:i+len(word)]
        if all(char in word for char in prop) and all(prop.count(char) == prop.count(word) for char in prop):
            print prop
```

Note, that if your file has only the two words "hi" and "there" as "hithere", and you look for the anagrams of "ith", `"hit"` will be printed

Comment: @JasonSchayer: What is the input on which it fails? What was it supposed to produce on that input and how is that different from what it did produce?